# How to solve the problem of not finding mapper when connecting to multiple databases in Spring Boot

Tags: xml, spring, datasource, mybatis, mapper

Good morning. I am developing with SpringBoot 2.4.4, and I use gradle, mybatis, and mysql.

The function currently being implemented performs the following operations when the button is clicked.

1. Let the user input values on the screen, and click the button after entering all the values.
2. To insert the value entered by the user and the currently accessed Locale information together
   Search the required columns from the product table of the database called exerd. (Select)
3. Map the value entered by the user + locale information to the columns obtained from the product table of the exerd database. (Locale is obtained through Java's Locale.)
4. And INSERT it to the place called exerdweb2.estimate_sheetinfo.

Here, the database for querying (exerd) and the database for entering values (exerdweb2) are different.

In order to connect multiple DBs, various information was found and configured as follows.

1. To connect two DATABASES, application.properties is written as follows.

> application.properties

```
mybatis.mapper.locations: classpath:**/*.xml
spring.datasource.hikari.exerd.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.hikari.exerd.jdbc-url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/exerd?                
serverTimezone=UTC&characterEncoding=UTF-8
spring.datasource.hikari.exerd.username=[id]
spring.datasource.hikari.exerd.password=[password]
spring.datasource.hikari.exerd.connection-test-query=SELECT 1

spring.datasource.hikari.exerdweb2.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.hikari.exerdweb2.jdbc-url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/exerdweb2? 
serverTimezone=UTC&characterEncoding=UTF-8
spring.datasource.hikari.exerdweb2.username=[id]
spring.datasource.hikari.exerdweb2.password=[password]
spring.datasource.hikari.exerdweb2.connection-test-query=SELECT 1
```

2.When the button is clicked, the sendBuyEstimation method is called, and the getEstimateSheetModel(estimatSheetModel) method is called for the 2 selections written above.

> EstimateService.java

```
    public String sendBuyEstimation(HttpServletRequest request, EstimateSheetModel estimatSheetModel) {
    
    EstimateSheetModel purchaseQuotationSheet = getEstimateSheetModel(estimatSheetModel);
```

3. For select, service, mapper, xml are called in the following order:

> EstimateService.java

```
private EstimateSheetModel getEstimateSheetModel(EstimateSheetModel estimatSheetModel) {
    ProductVO productVO = productService.getServiceProductInfo();
    // more code...
}
```

> getServiceProductInfo.java

```
import com.tomato.exerd.web.payment.product.vo.ProductVO;

@Repository
@Mapper
public interface ProductMapper {
    public ProductVO getServiceProductInfo();
}
```

> product.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!DOCTYPE mapper PUBLIC "-//mybatis.org//DTD Mapper 3.0//EN" "http://mybatis.org/dtd/mybatis-3-mapper.dtd">
<mapper namespace="com.tomato.exerd.web.payment.product.mapper.ProductMapper">
    <select id="getServiceProductInfo" resultType="com.tomato.exerd.web.payment.product.vo.ProductVO">
        SELECT
                productSeq
            ,   productName
            ,   productVersion
            ,   remark
            ,   insertDate
            ,   updateDate
            ,   volumePrice
            ,   projectPrice
        FROM    exerd.product
        WHERE serviceIn = 'y'
    </select>
</mapper>
```

4. So far there was no problem. Now we're going to make the insert perform a query.
   However, it was difficult to execute insert query using mybatis, so I had to select and test.

> sendBuyEstimation.java

```
public String sendBuyEstimation(HttpServletRequest request, EstimateSheetModel estimatSheetModel) {
 // more source...
 EstimateSheetModel model =  estimateSheetDBService.getInfo();
}
```

> EstimateSheetDBService.java (Up to this point it is called normally.)

```
@Service
public class EstimateSheetDBService {

@Autowired
private EstimateMapper estimateMapper;

public EstimateSheetModel getInfo() {
    // Up to this point it is called normally.
    return estimateMapper.getEstimateSheetInfo();
    
}
```

> EstimateMapper.java

```
package com.tomato.exerd.web.payment.estimate.mapper;

import org.apache.ibatis.annotations.Mapper;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.tomato.exerd.web.payment.estimate.model.EstimateSheetModel;

@Repository
@Mapper
public interface EstimateMapper {
    public EstimateSheetModel getEstimateSheetInfo();
}
```

> Estimate.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!DOCTYPE mapper PUBLIC "-//mybatis.org//DTD Mapper 3.0//EN" "http://mybatis.org/dtd/mybatis-3-mapper.dtd">
<mapper namespace="com.tomato.exerd.web.payment.estimate.mapper.EstimateMapper">
    <select id="getEstimateSheetInfo" resultType="com.tomato.exerd.web.payment.estimate.model.EstimateSheetModel">
        select
                id
            ,   isUpgrade 
     from exerdweb2.estimate_sheet_info
    </select>
</mapper>
```

And the datasource for each db is configured as follows.

> ExerdDataSourceConfig.java

```
@Configuration
@MapperScan(basePackages = "com.tomato.exerd.web.payment")

public class ExerdDataSourceConfig {

    @Bean(name="exerdDataSource")
    @ConfigurationProperties("spring.datasource.hikari.exerd")
    public DataSource exerdDataSource() throws Exception{
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().type(HikariDataSource.class).build();
    }
}
```

> ExerdWeb2DataSourceConfig.java

```
@Configuration
@MapperScan(basePackages = "com.tomato.exerd.web.payment")

public class ExerdWeb2DataSourceConfig {

    @Bean(name="exerdweb2DataSource")
    @ConfigurationProperties("spring.datasource.hikari.exerdweb2")
    public DataSource exerdweb2DataSource() throws Exception{
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().type(HikariDataSource.class).build();
    }
}
```

> MybatisConfig.java

```
@Configuration
public class MybatisConfig {

@Autowired
@Qualifier(value = "exerdDataSource")
private DataSource exerdDataSource;

@Autowired
@Qualifier(value = "exerdweb2DataSource")
private DataSource exerdweb2DataSource;

@Bean
@Primary
public SqlSessionFactory exerdSqlSessionFactoryBean() throws Exception {
    SqlSessionFactoryBean sqlSessionFactoryBean = new SqlSessionFactoryBean();
    sqlSessionFactoryBean.setDataSource(exerdDataSource);
    Resource[] resources = new PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver().getResources("classpath:product/*.xml");
    sqlSessionFactoryBean.setMapperLocations(resources);

    sqlSessionFactoryBean.setTypeAliasesPackage("com.tomato.exerd.web.payment");

    SqlSessionFactory sqlSessionFactory = sqlSessionFactoryBean.getObject();

    org.apache.ibatis.session.Configuration configuration = sqlSessionFactory.getConfiguration();
    configuration.setMapUnderscoreToCamelCase(true);

    return sqlSessionFactory;
}

@Bean
public SqlSessionFactory exerdweb2SqlSessionFactoryBean() throws Exception {
    SqlSessionFactoryBean sqlSessionFactoryBean = new SqlSessionFactoryBean();
    sqlSessionFactoryBean.setDataSource(exerdweb2DataSource);

    Resource[] resources = new PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver().getResources("classpath:estimate/*.xml");
    sqlSessionFactoryBean.setMapperLocations(resources);

    sqlSessionFactoryBean.setTypeAliasesPackage("com.tomato.exerd.web.payment");

    SqlSessionFactory sqlSessionFactory = sqlSessionFactoryBean.getObject();
    
    org.apache.ibatis.session.Configuration configuration = sqlSessionFactory.getConfiguration();
    configuration.setMapUnderscoreToCamelCase(true);
    return sqlSessionFactory;
}

@Bean
@Primary
public SqlSession exerdSqlSession() throws Exception {
    return new SqlSessionTemplate(exerdSqlSessionFactoryBean());
}

@Bean
public SqlSession exerdweb2SqlSession() throws Exception {
    return new SqlSessionTemplate(exerdweb2SqlSessionFactoryBean());
}
```

}

The package composition is as follows.
[image]

However, I keep getting the following error:org.apache.ibatis.binding.BindingException:

**Invalid bound statement (not found): com.tomato.exerd.web.payment.product.Mapper.ProductMapper.getServiceProductInfo**

I found a lot of information regarding that error, mostly just a solution to beware of typos and whitespace. I checked it carefully with reference to this, but there was no problem.

I don't quite understand, so I ask for help and thank you in advance.

Comment: The package name of `ProductMapper` does not match the namespace specified in the XML mapper. You should change the package `Mapper` to `mapper`.

Comment: @ave I referenced the comments, but I still get the same error.

Control + left-click on the mapper namespace in xml to open the corresponding mapper file was already confirmed.

What's the problem?

Comment: Hm...the error message should change, at least (i.e. `Mapper` -> `mapper`). There are many oddities in your config (e.g. you specify `mybatis.mapper.locations` then call `sqlSessionFactoryBean.setMapperLocations` and then use `@MapperScan`; which implies you copied those snippets from various sites without understanding it :D). Also, with your setup, there will be two sets of the same mappers (e.g. one `ProductMapper` for `exerd` and another for `exerdweb2`) which probably is not what you want. Have you considered using `AbstractRoutingDataSource`?

Comment: @ave No, AbstractRoutingDataSource is not considered.

As a result of my own search, estimate/Estimate.xml, product/Product.xml under src/main/resources
As mapper/Estimate.xml and mapper/Product.xml , the structure has been changed into one package.

And, in MybatisConfig.java, exerdSqlSessionFactoryBean() method and exerdweb2SqlSessionFactoryBean() method
getResource both getResources("classpath:mapper/*.xml");

If set to , it loaded normally. What's the problem?

Comment: What I meant was: you should consider using `AbstractRoutingDataSource` because the setup will be simpler. If you changed something, you should update the question.